# Need to short or write code in better way

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am not good with PHP coding, I need help with the following.

I have this in a loop:

```
$pageid = get_queried_object_id();

if (stripos($pageid, '1' )!=false){ 
    echo "$intro_sub_field_value_0";
}

elseif (stripos($pageid, '2' )!=false){
    echo "$intro_sub_field_value_1";
}

elseif (stripos($pageid, '3' )!=false){
    echo "$intro_sub_field_value_2";
}

elseif (stripos($pageid, '4' )!=false){
    echo "$intro_sub_field_value_3";
}

elseif (stripos($pageid, '5' )!=false){
    echo "$intro_sub_field_value_4";
}

elseif (stripos($pageid, '6' )!=false){
    echo "$intro_sub_field_value_5";
}

elseif (stripos($pageid, '7' )!=false){
    echo "$intro_sub_field_value_6";
}

elseif (stripos($pageid, '8' )!=false){
    echo "$intro_sub_field_value_7";
}

elseif (stripos($pageid, '9' )!=false){
    echo "$intro_sub_field_value_8";
}

else {
    echo "$intro_sub_field_value_0";
}
```

It's working fine but I need to short this code. So that if there are 5 or 50 or 100 or 1000 loop, i don't need to add or less.

Comment: You want to find the number, store it in a variable, and then `echo "$intro_sub_field_value_" + ($number - 1)`

Comment: @meagar `+`, in that place, in PHP? Probably rather not :-) I think they need variable variables here, https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: I think @CBroe is right. variable variables will work here. But as I am not good with PHP, I cannot understand how to fix that.

Comment: BTW, I forget to add following line in top:
$pageid = get_queried_object_id();

Comment: @CBroe Consider it pseudocode

Answer (score 0):

```
$page_id = get_queried_object_id();
    for($counter = 1 ; $counter <= 100 ; $counter++) {
        if ($page_id == $counter) {
            $var_name = 'intro_sub_field_value_' . ($counter - 1);
            echo $$var_name;
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you @Siavash Ebrahimi but it's not working. It's only showing the number, not the text.
BTW, I forget to add following line in top: $pageid = get_queried_object_id(); 
Could you please check the code again?

Comment: @HasiburRahman get_queried_object_id() returns an integer value, You dont need stripos for comparision, just use == operator, i edited the answer, Check it out.